# Converting binary strings to Buffers in Node.js

Tags: node.js, binary

I have a web service that takes a base 64 encoded string representing an image, creates a thumbnail of that image using the imagemagick library, then stores both of them in mongodb. I am doing this with the following code (approximately):

```
var buf = new Buffer(req.body.data, "base64"); //original image

im.resize({ srcData: buf, width: 256 }, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    this.thumbnail = new Buffer(stdout, "binary");
    //store buf and stdout in mongo
});
```

You will notice that I am creating a Buffer object using the "binary" encoding, which the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer) say not to do:

> 'binary' - A way of encoding raw binary data into strings by using
>   only the first 8 bits of each character. This encoding method is
>   deprecated and should be avoided in favor of Buffer objects where
>   possible. This encoding will be removed in future versions of Node.

First off I'm not sure what they are saying there. I'm trying to create a Buffer object and they seem to imply I should already have one.

Secondly, the source of the problem appears to be that the imagemagick resize method returns a string containing binary data. Doing typedef(stdout) return "string" and printing it out to the screen certainly appears to show a bunch of non-character data.

So what do I do here? I can't change how imagemagick works. Is there another way of doing what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

Thats how I am doing the same with success, storing images in mongodb.

```
//original ---> base64
var thumbnail = new Buffer(req.body.data).toString('base64');
//you can store this string value in a mongoose model property, and save to mongodb

//base64 ---> image
var buffer = new Buffer(thumbnail, "base64");
```

I am not sure if storing images as base64 is the best way to do it

Comment: In my case storying them as base64 strings still won't work because the imagemagick library doesn't return them that way. It appears to be a string that actually contains non-character bytes. I guess, I'm not really sure. I think I'll contain the owners of that library and ask them what's going on.

Comment: Hummmm... but, did you even try the approach I suggested? I guess image magick should return it as binary data, right? In this case it is still valid to convert this binary data to its base64 representation, and when retrieving convert **from** base64.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this as your base64 might not be pre-handled:

```
var imgRawData =
    req.body.images[0].replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,|^data:image\/jpeg;base64,|^data:image\/jpg;base64,|^data:image\/bmp;base64,/, "");

var yourBuffer = new Buffer(imgRawData, "base64");
```

Then, save the yourBuffer into MongoDB buffer.